# How to add parameters to a OleDbDataWriter

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net

I am getting an syntax error when I am trying to write to a excel file using ADO.NET. How can i add parameters to the query. I am updating a mysql database.

```
string error="Text for status";
string connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;";

System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection ExcelConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connectionString);
string ExcelQuery;

ExcelQuery = "Update [Sheet1$] set Status="+error; // from Sheet1";

//Create the command to be executed
ExcelCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(ExcelQuery, ExcelConnection);

//Open the connection to the file
ExcelConnection.Open();

//Execute the update
ExcelCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Close the connection
ExcelConnection.Close();
```

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Text for the
>   status'.

Comment: I am updating the status column in the excel with the string error. should I add parameters to it or can I do it without parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [OleDbCommand.Parameters.Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx) for adding parameters to the Command.

```
public void CreateMyOleDbCommand(OleDbConnection connection,
    string queryString, OleDbParameter[] parameters) 
{
    OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.CommandText = 
        "SELECT CustomerID, CompanyName FROM Customers WHERE Country = ? AND City = ?";
    command.Parameters.Add(parameters);

    for (int j=0; j<parameters.Length; j++)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(parameters[j]) ;
    }

    string message = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < command.Parameters.Count; i++) 
    {
        message += command.Parameters[i].ToString() + "\n";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(message);
}
```

Comment: Adding parameters to the oleDbCommand is same for either "Update" or "Select" or "Insert".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing `'` from your `UPDATE` statement.

`ExcelQuery = "Update [Sheet1$] set [Status]='" + error + "'";`

Comment: I am getting the same error after doing the changes  Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ''